# In app purchase testing with iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to test In App Purchases Non Consumable sandbox with iOS simulator? I have tried with Xcode 5.1.1 and it's not working.

Comment: You should really consider updating you Xcode. 5.1.1 is old and build are no longer excepted by Apple.

Comment: you might want to list more steps than that. For instance, what iOS version are you running, how did you setup your sandbox tester, what steps did you take to validate it wasn't working etc

Comment: you can't connect to the sandbox on iOS 7 and below in simulator...

Comment: is it possible with Xcode 6 ?